# How to loop the data from cloud firebase collection to get distance between user and other users in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the longitude and latitude of all users in cloud-firebase and I wanted to loop the data to get the distance between the user and other users and put a condition if the distance is <200 m between the user and users, a notification will appear to notify the user that someone is close to you. Can I have suggestions of any tutorial videos that teach this?

[image: This is my cloud collection data]

Answer (score 0):

While Firestore can **store** lat/lon data, it has no built-in functionality to query the pairs. If you want to be able to query for documents within a certain range from a specific point, you will need to:

1. Add a so-called geohash to each document, which encoded the lat/lon into a single value.
2. Then query on that geohash value to find documents that may be in range.
3. Post-process the documents in your application code, to verify their actual distance.

This entire process is quite well documented nowadays in the Firebase solution page for [running geoqueries on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries). If you have a bit more time, I also recommend watching the video of my talk on the topic from a few years ago: [Querying Firebase and Firestore based on geographic location or distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).